# HTML / CSS: Experiencing Issues Regarding Site Width / Height

Tags: html, css

I am in the process of setting up a website advertising a region for people to visit as a task for myself.

I have spent some time attempting to place all I have done so far all on one page. I wish for there to be no scrollbars, I do not want to make the scrollbars invisible or so forth, I mean have the web page fit on one page of the browser without the user having the need to scroll for aesthetic purposes.

I have played around with the width and height of divs along with a number of other things in an attempt to achieve my desired result but with no success unfortunately. What would I be required to change regarding my code in order to achieve this?

```css
body,
td,
th {
  font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#navigation {
  color: white;
  background-color: #292526;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
}
#navigationLeft {
  width: 24.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 180%;
}
#navigationRight {
  width: 74.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#navigation ul {
  float: right;
}
#navigation ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#navigation a {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#banner {
  line-height: 0;
}
#footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #292526;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.5% 0.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="navigation">
    <div id="navigationLeft">
      <a href="#">Visit Clare Ireland</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navigationRight">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Maps |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Appartments |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Attractions |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Essentials |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Bars & Clubs |</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Transport</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VsIRZNZ.jpg" alt="The Cliffs of Moher" />
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <p>Placeholder Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So..  should it scale?

Comment: As in, no matter what resolution, aspect ratio, etc., it will always fit on one page without having the need for the user to scroll? - Yes

Comment: Are you looking to resolve it within `CSS` only? If so, use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), otherwise you could achieve that via `JavaScript/jQuery`. And you could use something like [that](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) as well, applied to the main div.

Comment: I have never used media queries before, I have been doing HTML / CSS for a couple of months and haven't got on to them. I assume there would be another way to go about doing it through CSS?

Comment: Take a look to my second link (edited comment), it might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to the following:

[Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeRWGM)

Its not much but gives an idea, but it will also depend on the screen content and how much you want on there, too much then this could cause an issue, minimalistic then fine but the kitchen sink then ouch!

```
      <div class="container">
      <header>
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">Visit Clare Ireland</a>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Maps |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Hotels |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Appartments |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Attractions |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Essentials |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Bars & Clubs |</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Transport</a>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis quis laborum, ea repellat! Eius sint, minima nulla asperiores excepturi. Fuga libero exercitationem soluta nam perspiciatis, sit iusto enim asperiores quibusdam.

        </section>

      </main>
      <footer>
        <p>Footer content</p>  
      </footer>
      </div>
```

CSS

```
      html,
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", monospace;
        font-size: 16px;
      }


      header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 80px;
        background: #292526;
        color: white;
        overflow: hidden;
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      header:before,
      header:after {content: " ";display: table;}
      header:after {clear: both;}

      header .logo {
        margin-top: 20px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 40%;
      }

      header nav {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
        text-align: left;
      }

      header a:link,
      header a:visited,
      header a:active {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        padding-left: 20px;
        font-size: 26px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
      }

      nav ul {
        list-style: none;
      }

      nav ul li {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      nav ul li a:link,
      nav ul li a:visited,
      nav ul li a:active {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }

      main {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top:80px;
        bottom: 50px;
        left: 0;
        right:0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: white url('http://i.imgur.com/VsIRZNZ.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      main section {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        top: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        width: 93%;
        background: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
      }

      footer {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 40px;
        background: #292526;
        color: white;
      }
      footer p {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        padding-top: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
```